# How to use forward declaration in the following scenario

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I currently have the following two classes

```
class TOrder 
{
public:

private:
    .......
};
```

**Now my other class is :**

```
#include "TOrder.h"

namespace namespaceA
{
    namespace namespaceB
    {
        class OrderDis
        {
        private:
            TOrder* frmPointer;
                    .....
        };

    }       
}
```

The above works fine the problem starts when I use an object of OrderDis in TOrder as such

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "OrderDis"  //Added - Creates Problem
class TimedOrder 
{
public:

    .......
};
```

Any suggestion on how I could use forward declaration to resolve my issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could forward `OrderDispatcher` in TimeOrder.h

```
namespaceA
{
    namespaceB
    {
        class OrderDispatcher;
    }
}

class TimedOrder 
{
//...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As you only use a pointer to `TimedOrder` in the `OrderDispatcher` class, it can be solved by simply not including `TimedOrder.h` in the `OrderDispatch.h` file. Instead just *declare* the `TimedOrder` class:

```
class TimedOrder;
```

No need to muck about with namespaces and such then.

Note: You can't declare it in any of the namespaces, declare it instead where you now do your `#include`.

Answer (score 0):

The forward declaration can be written as:

```
namespace A{ namespace B{ class OrderDispatcher; } }
```